# Order of execution of trigger and workflow

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, order-of-execution

I am aware of the flow of execution in salesforce(validation, autoresponse, assignment...etc). I also have knowledge of the order of execution of a visualforce page. I have 2 questions on execution:

- Say, if there are 5 BEFORE INSERT triggers on Account object, which one will trigger first?
- Similarly, if I have 5 workflows on any object, what is the order of execution?

Or is it that order can be set only though code? I hope my question is not too wide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Bachovski pointed out, there is no way to control the execution order.  In the case of your 5 account triggers, you would likely want to combine all 5 triggers into a single trigger that calls a utility class with 5 methods.  Each method contains the logic of your old triggers.  This way, ***you do*** have control over the order of execution.

**Utility Class**

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {

     public static void myFirstMethod(list<Account> accs) {
          //your logic
     }
     public static void mySecondMethod(list<Account> accs) {
          //your logic
     }
     public static void myThirdMethod(list<Account> accs) {
          //your logic
     }
     public static void myFourthMethod(list<Account> accs) {
          //your logic
     }
     public static void myFifthMethod(list<Account> accs) {
          //your logic
     }
}
```

**Your new trigger**

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert){

     AccountTriggerHelper.myFirstMethod(trigger.new);
     AccountTriggerHelper.mySecondMethod(trigger.new);
     AccountTriggerHelper.myThirdMethod(trigger.new);
     AccountTriggerHelper.myFourthMethod(trigger.new);
     AccountTriggerHelper.myFifthMethod(trigger.new);
}
```

Then if you wanted to change the order of execution, you can just change a few lines around like below.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert){

         AccountTriggerHelper.myThirdMethod(trigger.new);
         AccountTriggerHelper.myFifthMethod(trigger.new);
         AccountTriggerHelper.mySecondMethod(trigger.new);
         AccountTriggerHelper.myFirstMethod(trigger.new);
         AccountTriggerHelper.myFourthMethod(trigger.new);

    }
```

Badda bing...you now can control the order of execution.  It's also much cleaner with only 1 trigger and 1 utility class to maintain, as opposed to maintaining multiple triggers.

Comment: No prob.  Glad to help :)

Answer (score 7):

It's described nicely in the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

> The order of execution isn’t guaranteed when having multiple triggers
>   for the same object due to the same event. For example, if you have
>   two before insert triggers for Case, and a new Case record is inserted
>   that fires the two triggers, the order in which these triggers fire
>   isn’t guaranteed.

So there is no way to determine which trigger will fire first, it might be a completely different order every time.

Best practice is to have only 1 trigger per object and have the code separated in a handler class to keep the trigger code nice and clean.

Comment: @MnZ here's a good salesforce developer blog by kevin on apex trigger patterns/frameworks : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

Comment: Thnks for the link krishna