# One object has Two triggers with same Event After insert

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com

I have Account object which have two Trigger, one trigger has events before insert and after insert second trigger has after insert event.

So which trigger will fire after the record is saved ?

Comment: Their is no reason second trigger wont fire could you please make sure that trigger is active.

Answer (score 3):

Both -  ideally you should only have one trigger per object. The issue with having multiple triggers, with the same event on the same object, is you cannot guarantee the order that they will execute.

From the Salesforce order of execution documentation:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

> The order of execution isn’t guaranteed when having multiple triggers
>   for the same object due to the same event. For example, if you have
>   two before insert triggers for Case, and a new Case record is inserted
>   that fires the two triggers, the order in which these triggers fire
>   isn’t guaranteed.

Also more information here:
[Order of execution of trigger and workflow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45276/order-of-execution-of-trigger-and-workflow)

If I had seen that answer before I probably would have flagged this question as a duplicate...

Comment: thanks for quick response. there is any documentation from salesforce related to this Case ?

Comment: I what to know weather Both Triggers will be executed or not ?

Comment: Added more detail in my answer, but you can easily see what triggers fire by either using the developer console or the debug logs.

Comment: As per my understanding both the Triggers will execute but we will not be able to define the order of execution, am I Write Girbot

Comment: Yup that's my understanding.

Comment: But my second trigger is not firing on After Insert Event, i tried by keeping System debug logs.

Comment: If the trigger isn't firing I would suggest raising another question and share the trigger code.

Comment: This is a good post on the one trigger method: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices

Comment: And this one from SF: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices